# When to catch boost::bad_lexical_cast

Tags: c++, boost, exception, casting

From the [documentation on the boost site for lexical cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) it states that when converting from a numeric type to a string type the conversion can throw a bad_lexical_cast. Clearly in this case we should always handle this exception should it be thrown.

My question is, what about the other way around, going from a numeric type to a string? This is less risky on operation but it does not state on the boost documentation whether this operation can throw a bad_lexical_cast although the example given ommits the catch block.

```
log_message("Error " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(yoko) + ": " + strerror(yoko));
```

Should I be catching a potential exception when converting from a numeric type to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no scenario in which an inbuilt numeric type can fail to be expressed in a string.

Comment: There is however a case where the conversion can fail - the string's memory allocation could throw.

Comment: That wouldn't be caught and re-thrown as a boost::bad_lexical_cast though?

Comment: It would be thrown as a std::bad_alloc. Boost might internally catch it and rethrow as something else, but I doubt a bad_lexical_cast.

Comment: It shouldn't, and I doubt it does. It didn't when I last looked.

Comment: It doesn't catch it, I just checked.

Comment: Wasn't suggesting that it does/should catch it, more that if it did, it would never rethrow as a bad_lexical_cast.